# why is @media screen and max-width miss firing on one computer?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a clients Wordpress site.  Recently noticed that one computer my client uses, just one, is taking on all the mobile & small screen styling rules and even Javascript that are detecting small screen and dynamically changing styles and elements on the page.

Here are some examples of these code and rules found hard coded all throughout the Wordpress theme.

CSS Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:992px){
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
/*And other styling for small screens here*/
}
```

And JS Example:

```
if($(window).width() <= 992 || $('body').hasClass('force-responsive')) {

    //resizeTimeoutMenu = setTimeout(function(){   
        $('.main-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a:first-child').not(".binded").addClass("binded").on("click",function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("mobile-menu-displayed");
            var parentContainer = $(this).parent("li");
            if(parentContainer.hasClass('menu-item-has-mega-menu')) {
                parentContainer.find('> .mega-menu').slideToggle();
            } else {
                parentContainer.find('> .sub-menu').slideToggle();
            }
            return false;
        });
    //}, 500);

}
```

All basically forcing a responsive design if the screen width is below 992px.

BUT this clients computer screen resolution is 1280x800.  Even when using an external monitor solo with even greater resolution width. And no matter what browser is used, no matter if its full screen or windowed small or big, no matter how much you drag the windowed browser width back and forth, .... a small screen below 992px is being detected and the responsive design is being forced.

All other computers this website is tested on work correctly, and the responsive design only kicks in when your resize your window below 992px.

What could be causing this to be happening on this one, my clients computer?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well what do you see if you `console.log($(window).width())`?

Comment: Place this piece of code inside the `JavaScript` file: `console.log($(window).width());`. Then check what pixel width is detected by `JavaScript`

Comment: Don't you need to specify units with jQuery, too? I don't see 'px' anywhere.

Comment: I'm gonna go with browser zoom, hit `Ctrl+0`

Comment: It does indeed sound like some kind of zooming is going on. Although I think it might even be a system setting since it occurs in all browsers.

Comment: I added the width output to the console log, it showed 1583 width at first, which still showed the mobile styling.  Then I told him to press ctrl 0.  Then width showed 1768 on another page refresh.  And then it showed normal styling!  Still don't understand how that works, even with a small amount of zoom making it 1583, that is still well above 992. so i don't know why it was showing mobile styling.